# Hyperlinks in section name

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, memoir

I am trying to use the `memoir` class to typeset a document in which the section headings function as hyperlinks to other locations in the document, using the `hyperref` package.  One of the ways that `\section` and \hyperlink don't really cooperate is that I can't call `\hyperlink` within a `\section` (`\section{\hyperlink{..}{...}`} causes an error).  To get around this, I found that I can get away with calling `\section` within the second argument of `\hyperlink`.  This workaround, however, has the unexpected and unwanted consequence of throwing off the spacing for quotations within that section.  I don't get the spacing between the bottom line of body text and the first line of quoted text that I would normally see.  I looked at the `hyperref` and `memoir` documentation and sources, but to be honest the `hyperref` code is pretty much impenetrable for me and I could not find a solution.  I can approximate one by manually line breaking at the end of the paragraph leading up to the quotation, but I would prefer a more elegant solution (and would like to understand what is going wrong).

Here is my MWE, which includes all of the packages I am calling.  I am using XeLaTeX.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names,hyperref}{xcolor}
\documentclass[article,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\hyperlink{a}{\section{what i want in the section, but not in the quote}}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\section{what i don't want in the section, but do in the quote}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

I understand that there are probably better ways to accomplish this task (`\ref`, etc.)  But the targets and links are already set up, and I would very strongly prefer not to recode them, as it would take some creative regex find and replace.  Which could easily go wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This variant defines `\slink` and `\sref`. They take a name as argument and precede a sectioning command. `\slink` then converts the section title to a link to the given target name. `\sref` uses the name as label name. The star form and the optional argument of the sectioning command is supported, examples:

```
\slink{a}\section{what i want in the section, ...}...\hypertarget{a}{...}
\sref{foo}\subsection*{Section with star}...\label{foo}
```

Links to the table of contents, the bookmarks, and the header lines are removed.
The full example file:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names,hyperref}{xcolor}
\documentclass[article,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{open,numbered}

\pagestyle{headings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slink}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \@ifstar{%
    \toks@{\endgroup#2*}%
    \slink@star{\texorpdfstring{\hyperlink{#1}}{}}%
  }{%
    \toks@{\endgroup#2}%
    \@ifnextchar[{%
      \slink@opt{\texorpdfstring{\hyperlink{#1}}{}}{#2}%
    }{%
      \slink@{\texorpdfstring{\hyperlink{#1}}{}}{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\sref}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \@ifstar{%
    \toks@{\endgroup#2*}%
    \slink@star{\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[{#1}]}{}}%
  }{%
    \toks@{\endgroup#2}%
    \@ifnextchar[{%
      \slink@opt{\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[{#1}]}{}}{#2}%
    }{%
      \slink@{\texorpdfstring{\hyperref[{#1}]}{}}{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}
\def\slink@star#1#2{%
  \the\toks@{#1{#2}}%
}
\def\slink@opt#1#2[#3]#4{%
  \the\toks@[{#3}]{#1{#4}}%
}
\def\slink@#1#2#3{%
  \the\toks@[{#3}]{#1{#3}}%
}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\slink{a}\section{what i want in the section, but not in the quote}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]   
\end{quote}  
\section{what i don't want in the section, but do in the quote}
\lipsum[3]
\hypertarget{a}{}
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[4]   
\end{quote}  

% more test cases
\newpage
\sref{eq:abc}\section{Section with link to equation}
\sref{eq:abc}\section*{Star section}
\sref{eq:abc}\section[Toc entry]{Section with link}
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\label{eq:abc}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you want (since you didn't provide a `\hypertarget`), but you can `\protect` the `\hyperlink` command and use `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,x11names,hyperref}{xcolor}
\documentclass[article,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\section{\texorpdfstring{\protect\hyperlink{a}{what i want in the section, but not in the quote}}{what i want in the section, but not in the quote}}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}
\section{what i don't want in the section, but do in the quote}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[4]
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

And perhaps, you might also want to use the optional argument(s) to prevent the link from appearing in an eventual ToC (or headers):

```
\section[Text for the ToC]{\texorpdfstring{\protect\hyperlink{a}{what i want in the section, but not in the quote}}{what i want in the section, but not in the quote}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case [@Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73841/127505)'s answer does not work with `hyperlink`, but substituting it with `href` does.