# How to use an hyperlink as a paragraph title?

Tags: hyperref, paragraphs, links, sections-paragraphs

I want to use the `hyperref` package to create hyperlinks in my pdf output.

I have a global table and I would like to link each line to a more detailed table further down the document. And for each detailed table, I would like the paragraph title to become an hyperlink to the global table.

The first part is not a problem (linking each line of the big table to a small detail table). I didn't find how to do the second one though (link the paragraph title to the global table).

Something like

```
\subparagraph{\hyperlink{my target here}{my title here}}
```

doesn't seem to work.

Anybody knows how to write this one ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73840/hyperlinks-in-section-name

Comment: interverting `\hyperlink` and `\subparagraph` doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of Gonzalo's answer on the linked page.

Comment: `\hypertarget{ALL-Global}{target Global}` ... `\slink{ALL-Global}{\subparagraph{my title here}}` is a no-go as well. The sref function doesn't seem to match what I was looking for either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section titles might appear in the table of contents or in the headers. Both is unlikely for `\subparagraph`, but who knows. This can be solved by using the optional argument to avoid linked titles at the other locations:

```
\subparagraph[My title]{\hypertarget{My target}{My title}}
```

Or, if there is a `\label` for the `\caption` of the global table:

```
\subparagraph[My title]{\hyperref[tab:globaltable]{My title}}
...
\caption{My global table}\label{tab:globaltable}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. 
I do not have a TOC in that document so no worries.
Replacing `hypertarget` with `hyperlink` in `\subparagraph[My title]{\hypertarget{My target}{My title}}` does work.
But I don't understand what the `[My title]` is supposed to represent. Changing it has no impact on my document. Is it a label of some sort ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Heiko Oberdiek's answer here is the final solution :

```
\subparagraph[My title]{\hyperlink{My target}{My title}}
```